# Webstorm breakpoints not working with grunt copy

Tags: gruntjs, webstorm, grunt-contrib-copy

As part of the dev workflow grunt-contrib-copy is copying files from **/src** to **/dist** where the node server & debugger are running.

When I create breakpoints within /dist everything works perfectly with the debugger, but when I create them in /src they don't copy over.

Is there any way of creating breakpoints in /src and have them picked up after the copy task?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to map your original files to the ones being actually executed. This is normally done with the help of sourcemaps. If the generated map files conform to Source Map Spec (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit?hl=en_US) and the generated files have the properly formatted `//@ sourceMappingURL` comment, debugging should work out of the box. But, AFAIK, **grunt-contrib-copy** module doesn't generate sourcemaps to map files in **dist** directory to files in **src** one...

Comment: found a solution without using sourcemaps... In javaScript debug run configuration you use to debug your client-side files served by your server, specify remote URL mappings for your 'src' folder - map it to your server URL

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this? I'm in the run/debug configuration settings. Thanks.

Comment: let you have your server listening on 'localhost:3000' and serving files from dist folder, whereas your source files are located in src directory. In your javaScript run configuration, double-click the 'Remote URL' column next to 'src' folder and enter 'http://localhost:3000' there